# Equality of Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
afile = "name.txt"
f = open(afile,"r")
content = f.readlines()
f.close()
correct = content[1]
answer = raw_input()
if answer == correct:
    print 'True'
```

Let say that, because of the name.txt, content[1] is George and then I run the code and I type George for answer.
Why I won't get True?
Why answer and correct are not the same?

Answer (score 6):

The data you read includes newlines; strip those from the lines first:

```
if answer == correct.strip():
```

which removes *all* whitespace from the start and end of a string. If whitespace at the start or end is important, you can remove *just newlines from the end* with:

```
if answer == correct.rstrip('\n'):
```

Comment: It might be prudent to also use `.lower()` if capitalization isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten a bit:

```
def get_file_line(fname, line_num):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        try:
            for _ in range(line_num + 1):
                line = inf.next()
            return line.rstrip('\r\n')
        except StopIteration:
            return None

if answer == get_file_line('name.txt', 1):
    print('True')
```